# How to retrieve ConfirmationToken in a .NET MVC 4 Web Application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, security

In my application I register an account using

```
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel m){
    // validation

    string confirmationToken = WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(m.email, m.Password, true);

    // send the token via email to confirm the email
    return View("WaitingForEmailVerification");
}
```

I want to implement a function that resend a second Confirmation email in case of failure of the first.

```
public ActionResult ResendConfirmationEmail(string username){
    // validation

    string confirmationToken = ...........

    // send the toke via email to confirm the email
    return View("WaitingForEmailVerification");
}
```

Is there any way with Membership class or WebSecurity to retrieve the confirmationToken?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: the only exception that may occur would be InvalidOperationException. Put your code in a try except block and you will capture it

Comment: Also, you can use WebSecurity.IsConfirmed Method to check if the user has confirmed the token..

Comment: I have to put WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(....) in a try catch?

Comment: Depends on which kind of failure you expect...

Comment: Ok, If user delete email? I want to give the possibility to the user to resend email verification with the token

Comment: I thought about a partial solution: store the ConfirmationToken in the UserProfile table at the registration time so I can retrieve it when I want